# Option clash for package natbib only for Windows and Unix

Tags: xetex, natbib

I'm testing a template. It works fine on OS X using MacTex2019, but error with texlive2020 both on Windows and Unix. What's happening?

error:

```latex
\RequirePackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}
\RequirePackage[sort&compress]{gbt7714}

\RequirePackage{hypernat}
```

log on OSX:

```
...
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/gbt7714/gbt7714.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hypernat/hypernat.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/hypcap.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/footmisc/footmisc.sty)
...
```

log on Windows:

```
...
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/gbt7714/gbt7714.sty

! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package natbib.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.63 \RequirePackage
                    {url}
?
```

log on Unix:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/gbt7714/gbt7714.sty

! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package natbib.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.63 \RequirePackage
                    {url}
?
```

After commented out `\RequirePackage[sort&compress]{gbt7714}`, it can be successfully complied, but with incorrect citing and without references chapter.

Comment: texlive 2020 contains `gbt7714` v2.0.1, while texlive 2019 contains older version. Starting at v2.0, `gbt7714` changes its usage. I think you can just comment the line `\RequirePackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}` in texlive 2020. And v2.0 requires explicit use of `\bibliographystyle`. See the [package manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/gbt7714/gbt7714.pdf) (in Chinese) for detailed info.

Comment: Thanks！It worked